# Updating stock in different ways, which one would be quicker using php?

Tags: php, arrays, database, woocommerce, compare

I'm getting trying to update stock quantity from a database automatically using php.

The database has **11,000** results that I need to sift through, the website that I'm updating has **100** results.

What way do you think would be better to do this? I grab an array of sku numbers from the website, then for each of those results, find the same sku from the database and then update the stock from there? Or get the array from the website, get an array from the database, compare and then update? Which would be quicker? or is there a way that I haven't thought of?

**EDIT** Sorry I should've added more info. There are 2 different sites that will be buying and selling from the stock in the warehouse. It's all controlled from an erp system that they have set up. So, I need it updated from that, which is the database that I mentioned earlier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your website has the sku number and the stock count for each product? If so, your webpage will pass the sku number and stock count in a form post to an update function.

The update function can then do the update based on the array of sku numbers and the corresponding array of stock count.

Comment: Sorry I should've added more info. There are 2 different sites that will be buying and selling from the stock in the warehouse. It's all controlled from an erp system that they have set up. So, I need it updated from that, which is the database.